# Validating angularjs forms created within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am dynamically creating multiple forms using ng-repeat, and i need to validate each one independently but it seems that I cannot dynamically set a form name and then validate it dynamically.

```
<div ng-repeat="quote in quotes" ng-form="quote{{$index}}" novalidate>

  <div ng-if="quote$index.$invalid">INVALID</div>

</div>
```

How would i validate forms separately that are dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked these posts?

- http://triangular.io/blog/form-validation-vs-ng-repeat/ (here is a solution based on a custom directive)
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform (here is a solution based on ngForm)

Comment: Yes, but these tutorials do not explain how to validate multiple forms, independently.